# Подскажите книгу для изучения Java

Tags: java, android

Подскажите книги для изучения Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вас интересует изучение самой Java, то посоветую смотреть видео-лекции по языку или записаться на семинар.

Ну а если нужны именно книги, то вот список:

- Java SE 8 Вводный курс (Кей Хортсман)
- Java. Библиотека профессионала (2 тома. Кей Хортсман)
- Философия Java (Брюс Эккель)

Comment: Нет я предпочитаю книги. Спасибо за список

Comment: @DavidSargsyan также к себе в библиотеку я добавил следующее:
1. Spring 4 Для профессионалов (Крис Шефер и др.)
2. Изучаем Java EE 7 (Энтони Гонсалвес)
3. Структуры данных и алгоритмы в Java (Роберт Лафоре)

Comment: А какая книга лучше для новичков ?

Comment: @DavidSargsyan это уже индивидуально. Я начинал с "Java. Библиотека профессионала". Прочел оба тома и выбрал темы, которые нужно разбирать тщательнее, которые не понятны сразу. Далее я уже искал дополнительную литературу.

Очень помогла книга **"Java 8. Полное руководство"** Герберта Шидта. Но она не является учебником, а скорее дополнительным материалом при изучении Java. Также советую все-таки соединять книги и видео-лекции. От себя могу посоветовать [Сергея Немчинского](https://www.youtube.com/user/pro100fox2). Я начинал так.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй [Android 6 для профессионалов 2015](https://vk.com/doc273848965_437760512?hash=de3600d414e26ba6ca&dl=c1e300feeec5826991)

Актуальная книга на **русском языке** с упором на практику со множеством примерами и подробными объяснениями, в которой автор затрагивает большинство аспектов фреймфорка, дающие достаточно знаний для **старта** кодинга на Android.

Comment: Мне вообще-то для новичков надо было но все равно спасибо